# Field "Tracking" from the Form template is throwing an exception

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore8.1

I am having some issues getting the WFFM (Web Forms for Marketers) 8.1 to work in a Sitecore 8.1 solution .... and I guess the reason is the below error that I get on the **Tracking** field from the **Advanced section** *(Standard fields)*.

Does anyone have a clue why I get this error on the clean WFFFM installation? Thank you in advance. ***(log below)***

[image]

**Exception:**

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: item]

```
 `Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName) +63
   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.<GetDescendants>d__8.MoveNext() +98
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator 2.MoveNext() +118
   System.Linq.<ConcatIterator>d__58 1.MoveNext() +178
   System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator 1.MoveNext() +108
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable 1 source) +147
        Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.TrackingField.TrackingFieldDetailsPage.RenderEvents(HtmlTextWriter output, XDocument doc, IEnumerable 1 pageEventDefinitions, Boolean isGoals, Boolean isFailures) +362
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.TrackingField.TrackingFieldDetailsPage.RenderTracking(HtmlTextWriter output, XDocument doc) +379
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.TrackingField.TrackingFieldDetailsPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +409
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +165
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4498`
```

**Update:** tried to install the newest version of WFFM 8.1 Update 2 but I see the same issue. Also tried to install the WFFM against new clean Core and Master databases and I get an error I was previously getting .. **Post condition failed.**

[image]

Comment: Is this the initial version of Sitecore 8.1? There were a number of errors with WFFM in that version and is recommended to use a newer release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like there's an issue with your config.

One thing to check, make sure you have `analyticsDefinitions="content"` specified on the defintion of your `shell` site in your web.config

Failing this try to Deploy Marketing Definitions in Control Panel -> Analytics.

Comment: Thank you Ian! Indeed, the analyticsDefinitions tag was missing from my sitecore.config. Adding this fixed the error on the Tracking fields.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to fix the issues with WFFM after upgrading from 7 to 8.1. The exception I was getting on the Tracking field was related to the answer above .. the `analyticsDefinitions="content"` attribute was missing from the `shell` website.

Also there was a bug related to the Tracking field, throwing an exception "Unrecognized guid format" which was crashing WFFM. The below article solved the second issue.
https://reasoncodeexample.com/2015/03/26/sitecore-linkdatabase-unrecognized-guid-format/